# Show uniform convergence using continuous function

Tags: compactness, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

Let $(\mathcal{C},d_\infty)$ be a compact metric space and let $C\in\mathcal{C}$ be equicontinuous and defined as $C_A(x,y)=(xy)^{A\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(xy)}\right)}$ with $x,y\in(0,1)$ and let $A:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a convex function and let $\Phi:(\mathcal{A},\lVert \cdot \rVert_\infty)\to(\mathcal{C},d_\infty)$ with $\Phi(A)=C_A$.

I have to show that:
$$
A_n \to A \text{ uniform } \iff C_n\to C \text{ uniform }
$$

"$\Rightarrow$"  i think this direction is clear for me
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} C_{A_n}(x,y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(xy)^{A_n\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(xy)}\right)}=(xy)^{A\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(xy)}\right)}=C_A(x,y)
$$
and because the $C's$ are equicontinuous and $\mathcal{C}$ is compact, pointwise convergence equals uniform convergence (Corollar of Arzelà-Ascoli). (can someone tell me if this is right?)

"$\Leftarrow$" i have problems proving this direction. I think i have to use $\Phi$ because it's in the introduction of the problem.
But i don't know which properties i could use. I only see that $\Phi$ has to be continuous, since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Phi (A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} C_{A_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(xy)^{A_n\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(xy)}\right)}=(xy)^{A\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(xy)}\right)} =C_A=\Phi(A).
$$
Having this how can i show that $A_n\to A$ uniform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then for any uniformly continuous function (say $g$), $g(f_n)$ converges to $g(f)$ uniformly.  (why ?)

Also $f_n(g)$ converges uniformly to $f(g)$ for any continue function $g$. (why?)

Therefore, $ln(C_n) = A_n(\frac{ln(x)}{ln(xy)}) ln(xy)$ converges uniformly to $ln(C)$.

Now use product of uniformly continuously functions is uniformly countinous, to show $A_n(\frac{ln(x)}{ln(xy)}) \  ln(xy)$ converges uniformly to $\frac{ln(C)}{ln(xy} = A(\frac{ln(x)}{ln(xy)})$